# Integromat & Wild Apricot

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am absolutely new to Integromat and looking for some guidance. I am trying to download data files from members of the Wild Aprico App to a google drive.
I am able to connect to Wild Apricot but I have no idea how to create a scenario to do that.
Many thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to experiment with the Wild Apricot "Search Contacts" module to grab the contacts you want with any (optional) filters. Once you run that you will return a set of bundles that match the criteria you set in the module if any. Then you can model a Google Sheet module to add a row. Create the sheet ahead of time with headers you can use in the Google Sheet integration, similar to the columns you wish to "sync" from Wild Apricot.

Now if you want to copy them and erase them on the target every run is another part of the scenario you will want to model. Or do you want to update any fields/rows that have changed? If you want to do an "upsert" to update data in the sheet that will be more complex but save operations.

Most Wild Apricot databases are not that large. You will use as many operations as the number of contacts (ie bundles) you have in each scenario run - each new contact insert into Google Sheets will be one operation.

Here's a 2 module starting point:

[image]